# What does context represent in these 3 diffeent positions

Tags: flutter

I am learning Flutter and studying right now to make navigations. But looking at the keyword context in different places confuses me:

```
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('My Page')),
      body: Center(
        child: TextButton(
          child: Text('POP'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
));
```

Could anyone explain what **context** represents in each case. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context` is basically all the meta data about your app (from my understanding). For example, it contains info about your theming, appearance, routing, sizing, appearance, device info, etc.

In the case of navigators, it’s used to indicate what route you’re currently on, so the navigator can properly `pop` it (remove it) or push to a new route (`.push`).

In the case of `BuildContext context`, this is the new `context` that’s being passed to your widget tree every time a build is called to the UI so that downstream widgets can use an updated `context` instead of a stale one.